defaultValue change when set value inside the state
I want to create a validation that compares the value and the default value, but when I set the value inside the state, the default value also changes to match the value.
We can check the default value and value from the ref
const [value, setValue] = useState('helo')

<form onChange={e => console.log(e)}>
  <input
    defaultValue={5}
    value={value}
    onChange={e => {
      const format = () => {};
      setValue(format(e.target.value))
    }
  />
</form>

But when the value is not controlled, the default value behaves as expected.
<form onChange={e => console.log(e)}>
  <input defaultValue={5} />
</form>


The defaultValue prop is used for uncontrolled inputs, whereas the value and onChange props are used for controlled inputs. Can you [edit] to clarify what use case you are trying to accomplish here using both? Note that this may mean updating to include a complete [mcve].

As Drew Reese stated in a comment, React is not designed to allow both defaultValue and value. Logically, the defaultValue is redundant if you have a value: its default value would be the starting value.
As can be seen in this pen using a simplified version of your code: https://codepen.io/Razzi-Abuissa/pen/ExBBdYm
function Example() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState('helo')

  return <form>
    <input defaultValue={5} value={value} onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)} />
  </form>
} 
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<Example />)

In the console you can see React give the following warning:

Warning: Example contains an input of type undefined with both value and defaultValue props. Input elements must be either controlled or uncontrolled (specify either the value prop, or the defaultValue prop, but not both). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element and remove one of these props. More info: https://reactjs.org/link/controlled-components

